# Consolidating Two Directives into a Single One

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

Suppose one has two predefined directives `dir1` and `dir2` ( which are provided by a 3rd party API that one has no control over). Let's say these can be applies to an html element as follows:

```html
<div dir1="red" [dir2]="123">... My Content ...</div>
```

I have found myself applying the above the directives with the exact same binding values in several places in my code. Rather than repeat myself, I would like to create my own custom directive, call it `myDir`, that I could apply like this:

```html
<div MyDir >... My Content ...</div>
```

This should be *exactly* the same as applying `dir1` and `dir2` as in the prior example above i.e. it will have the values `"red"` and `123` hard coded within it's class.

I have tried setting host bindings as in the following [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/W20Wvew326qsGfPU5H6v) example, but this doesn't work..

One idea I have is if only typescript had multiple inheritance, then I would simply write the `MyDir` class an extension of `Dir1` *and* `Dir2`..

My question is how do I go about writing the custom directive (`MyDir`) to achieve the intended use?

Kindly Assist,
Thanks You!

https://plnkr.co/edit/W20Wvew326qsGfPU5H6v

Comment: If the goal is that your directive adding attributes which results in the other directives being added, then this won't work. Directives are only added when the selector matches statically added HTML. There is no way to make directives being added dynamically. I also don't know another way, except reimplementing the functionality of the other 2 directives inside one directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Angular 15 you can use [Directive composition API](https://angular.io/guide/directive-composition-api). What you're looking for is [adding directives to another directive](https://angular.io/guide/directive-composition-api#adding-directives-to-another-directive)

Your example will be:

```
@Directive({
  hostDirectives: [Dir1, Dir2],
})
export class MyDir {
  dir1 = inject(Dir1, { self: true });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> **Update:** Still not possible in May 2020. It is on the Angular Team's feature backlog. Follow progress here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785

#### (TL;DR. For my hack soln, See [Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/TCagW8vOPrqSiOT9Oztf))

The following is what ended up being my solutions for the problem, as presented above. Note that this is not the most general solution; In other scenarios, it's adaptability will depend largely one what the public API of the directives involved looks like. It should work well where the directives to be combined have atleast [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) as one of the injection dependencies like:

```js
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, /*...*/) { /*...*/ }
```

This may well be the case if the directives are responsible for changing the styling of an element.

What I did was, I simply created two `new` `Dir1`/`Dir2` objects passing in the `MyDir`'s `ElementRef` as context for `Dir1`/`Dir2` like so:

```js
// inside MyDir constructor
this.d1 = new Dir1(this.elRef,  /*...*/);
this.d2 = new Dir2(this.elRef,  /*...*/);
```

Then I set the public properties (`@Input` bindings) of `d1`/`d2` to values I need them to permanently be (to avoid repeating myself):

```js
//inside MyDir constructor
this.d1.dir1 = "red";
this.d2.dir2 = 123;
```

Next, all I had to try and do was match up the public methods `d1`/`d2` with `MyDir` by invoking the former's methods inside the corresponding method(s) of the latter, e.g.

```js
ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.d1.ngAfterContentInit();
  this.d2.ngAfterContentInit();
}
```

Here is the plunker with this all pieced together
https://plnkr.co/edit/TCagW8vOPrqSiOT9Oztf